# How do I download and install the Qt library?

Tags: c++, qt, include

I want to use the QDirIterator Class for a University Project in Visual Studio, but for some reason I just can't include it. I tried downloading the libary somewhere but couldn't find the right website, the QT website itself seems to be a messy jungle of paywalls.

The error message Visual Studio gives me is 'cannot open source file "QDirIterator"'. I have some Python knowledge so maybe I can do something similar like pip install?

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.14/qdiriterator.html link to the documentation of the class I'm trying to use.

Comment: If you don't have a Qt installation you will not be able to include Qt headers. Is your real question "how do I download and install the Qt library"?

Comment: @Botje, yes you are right, I will edit the title to make it clearer.

Comment: As for "jungle of paywalls", click "go open source" on https://www.qt.io/download and then "download the qt online installer" at the bottom. **OR** get Qt from vcpkg / Conan.

Comment: If you are not programming with the  Qt framework you should use the filesystem library instead. [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator)

Comment: If you're only interested in using the QDirIterator class, and not the rest of the Qt library, this may be a bit of overkill for you. Qt is a very big set of libraries. It may make sense to find something simpler that's just for navigating a file a directory structure

Comment: I believe that using Qt is not free even for students. So I am doubtful that you want to use it.

Comment: @ALX23z please don't spread FUD. The open source version is licensed as LGPL3, GPL3 and GPL2. Your rights and responsibilities as a developer are clearly marked [on the download page](https://www.qt.io/download-open-source)

Comment: `Qt` is free to use however I would not use it for only the `QDirIterator`. If you have a old version of Visual Studio such that you can't use the filesystem library use boost instead. [https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#Class-directory_iterator](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#Class-directory_iterator)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I feel your pain, the Qt website is very hard to navigate. This is how I installed it. Open [this](http://download.qt.io/official_releases/online_installers/) link and hit "qt-unified-windows-x86-online.exe." (or the correct one for your operating system). Open the file and follow the steps. I would actually recommend you find a simpler library for your single needs because AFAIK you aren't going to use 99% of the libraries that come with Qt.

Comment: "Very hard to navigate" or literally impossible to navigate? Everywhere on there leads to https://www.qt.io/download which leads to the "product map" which leads nowhere. It feels like a scam...